FDF Import for PHP8?
I am trying to import FDF File Informations into php. Just very simple. Users have their fdf files from other resources and I want to create a website where they can upload it and the website takes some information (like name (text) or something else) and shows it on screen...
But all I can find from fdf_open (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fdf-open.php) seems to be very old and deprecated...
Is there a simple method to "read" fdf files with php?
I tried this:
$fdffp = fopen("test.fdf", "w");
fwrite($fdffp, $HTTP_FDF_DATA, strlen($HTTP_FDF_DATA));
fclose($fdffp);

$fdf = fdf_open("test.fdf");
$name = fdf_get_value($fdf,"Name");
echo $name;
fdf_close($fdf);

But there is an error in error.log
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fdf_open() in ...

I thought I had to install a FDF package or something for PHP on my Linux Apache Webserver, but I can
t find something...
Any ideas?
